# Prevent Bash word splitting in substring

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I prevent Bash from splitting words within a substring?
Here's a somewhat contrived example to illustrate the problem:

```
touch file1 'foo bar'
FILES="file1 'foo bar'"
ls -la $FILES
```

Is it possible to get 'foo bar' regarded as a single string by the ls command within $FILES that would effectively result in the same behavior as the following command?

```
ls -la file1 'foo bar'
```

Comment: You can't. [Use an array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) as kojiro suggests. Use the exact syntax as shown, the quotes are crucial.

Answer (score 16):

Use an array:

```
files=( file1 'foo bar' )
ls -la "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks. The context is actually such that I've a bash script (s1.sh) from which I'm calling another script (s2.sh). s2.sh in turn invokes a binary command cmd and passes value of CMD_OPTS environment variable as arguments. So preferably, I'd like to be able to set CMD_OPTS in s1.sh without actually modifying s2.sh at all.

Comment: @marko:  Not possible -- you must fix `s2.sh`.  Also, make sure the scripts are actually `bash` scripts and not `/bin/sh` scripts -- the POSIX shell doesn't support arrays.

Comment: While s1.sh can use Bash, s2.sh actually seems to require POSIX shell. Is there a way to simulate the array construct solution proposed by @kojiro using POSIX shell?

Comment: @marko: please ask that in a new question.  short answer:  yes, but it's ugly.

Answer (score 2):

kojiro's array solution is the best option here. 
Just to present another option you could store your list of files in `FILES` with a different field separator than whitespace and set `IFS` to that field separator

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
FILES="file1:foo bar"
IFS=':'; ls -la $FILES
IFS=$OLDIFS
```